# Trigger JQuery script once product has been successfully added to cart

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Inside my child theme's custom.js I have the following:

```
$(document.body).on('added_to_cart', function() {
    console.log('Product Added');
});
```

In theory, this should output that message in the console when a product has been successfully added to the cart. However, at the moment it does nothing and I cannot work out why?

Comment: `'added_to_cart'` must be an event. Is this event customised or added?

Comment: You have certainly make some other customizations (or your theme has some or even a plugin can be guilty)… without a live link is not possible to check what is going wrong as the code that you are using should work on default woocommerce… Also this code will only work on archove pages as shop, is ajax add to cart is enabled in Woocommerce settings.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
        alert("testing!");
    });
});
```

Use this it works for me..:)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine for me...

**HTML (w/ Bootstrap 4)**

```
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="col-4 mx-auto">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body text-center">
        <h5>Hello, World!</h5>
        <br>
        <button id="addToCart" class="btn btn-primary">
          Trigger Event
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var body = $(document.body);
var button = $('#addToCart');

body.on('add_to_cart', function (event) {
  console.log('added to cart!');
});

button.on('click', function () {
  body.trigger('add_to_cart');
})
```

You can check out this CodePen and play around with it:
 https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZjBoNY?editors=1010